# how to get new line in __repr__() in python flask?

Tags: html, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

[image]

I made the comment section for my blog page, but the problem is it showing name and comment in a single line and I want both these in different lines. and \n is not working.

```py
class comments(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'comment'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text)
    comm = db.Column(db.Text)

    def __init__(self,name,comm):
        self.name = name
        self.comm = comm

    def __repr__(self):
        return f" Name: {self.name} Comment: {self.comm}"
```

function

```py
@app.route('/fat', methods=['GET','POST'])
def fat():

    form = AddForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        name = form.name.data
        comm = form.comm.data
        newname = comments(name,comm)
        db.session.add(newname)
        db.session.commit()

        return redirect(url_for('fat'))

    new = comments.query.all()


    return render_template('fat.html',form=form, newnames=new)
```

the code for fat.html is attached below......................................................................................................................................................

```
</div>
{% block content %}
<div class="post comment">
    {% for co in newnames %}
    <li>{{co}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</div>



<div class="myform">
    <h2>Leave a Comment</h2>
<form method="POST">

    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <div class="myforms">
    <h1 class="myform1"> {{ form.name.label }}</h1>
    <h1 class="myform2"> {{ form.name() }} </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="myformss">
    <h1 class="myform3">    {{ form.comm.label }} </h1>
    <h1 class="myform4"> {{ form.comm()}}</h1>

    </div>
    <div class="myformsss">
        <h1 class="myform5"> {{ form.submit() }} </h1>
    </div>



</form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not that flexible to do the HTML content layout in the backend. The display style should be decided on the front end. I mean, you should modify your `fat.html`.

If you need my help. Modify your question and paste out the content of `fat.html`.

---

Update:

```
<div class="post comment">
    {% for co in newnames %}
    <li>Name: {{ co.name }}</li>
    <li>Name: {{ co.comm }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Here's a simple example. You can access the `Comment` object just like what you do in Python.

You may need to change the css style to indent the comments block and make it align with the other blocks.

Comment: hey, I attached the fat.html file. please look into it